# Select iif sql multiple conditions in one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2012, resultset

We have multiple variables: Variable1, Variable2, and Variable3 in SQL Server 2012

If one of these variables fail, we out fail status

```
Declare @Variable1 int
Set @Variable1 = ( select  top 1 count(*)
FROM Table1
where condition1=1 
group by column1,column2
having count(1) >1)

Declare @Variable2 int
Set @Variable2 = ( select  top 1 count(*)
FROM Table1
where condition2=1 
group by column3,column4
having count(1) >1)

Declare @Variable3 int
Set @Variable3 = ( select  top 1 count(*)
FROM Table1
where condition3=1 
group by column5,column6
having count(1) >1)

SELECT IIF ( @Variable1 >=1 and Variable2 >=1 and Variable3 >=1, 'Fail', 'Pass' ) AS ResultTable1;
```

The ResultTable1 always get result base on @Variable1 and not base on @Variable2 and @Variable3 result

Can any one help? -thanks

Comment: I think that you should at least add some `ORDER BY` clauses in your queries (since you use top on all of them).

Comment: agreed, also select or print the values of these variables before you compare them.  What are they returning? Make sure there are no nulls.

Comment: I am able to get value of variable and I donot care the order. The issue is  ResultTable1 always get result base on Variable1 and not base on Variable2 and Variable3 result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If one of these variables fail, we out fail status

In that case, you need to use `OR` in your `IIF()`, not `AND`.  The way you have it now, ALL of the variables have to fail to have a failed status.

```
SELECT IIF ( @Variable1 >=1 OR @Variable2 >=1 OR @Variable3 >=1, 'Fail', 'Pass' ) AS ResultTable1
```